# ThinkTanking for design

Tags: wp-editor

I have a question that doesn't need scripting solutions perse.
I would like to have some idea's and people who think along with me.

WordPress: I have a script that let's a user upload a .csv file and views the content in a editor screen so the user can edit the form.

I have this script working: [View content from uploaded file in editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158262/view-content-from-uploaded-file-in-editor)

The next step is a design question (this is where you come in).
The whole reason why a user can edit the file is to make some "designy" modifications that can't be created in css because of their variability.
Let's say a user want's a specific cel **bold** or *italic*.
This is not something I can prepare for.

If a user saves the content and re-uploads a new .csv file all the "designy" things he made are gone and he needs to do them again. 
 This is where I need a solution. I need a way that the "designy" things are saved so they can be reapplied to the new table.

Also if the .csv file has an extra field or column the applied style must be added to the right cel.

This is a pickle because I simply have no clue how to even think about doing this.

I hope anyone can share their thoughts with me.

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress stores content data as text, which is considered either valid HTML or kind of "weak" HTML (without paragraphs markup, which are added by WP in processing). There are third party alternatives (such as Markdown) and embedded options (such as latex), but in principle it is HTML.

The presentational side of HTML can be changed via:

- HTML markup itself
- inline or external CSS

So any case other than external CSS *won't survive content overwrite*. And having users write CSS (more so involving tables and things like n-th cells) is unlikely to be any kind of practical.

So as stated this use case is nearly unsolvable in my opinion. The only thing I can think of to preserve changes is forbidding upload on top of existing content.

Stepping aside from content and plain text, tabular data can be parsed and stored in other representation — like array data structures or actual database table. In that case updating it with preserving changes becomes more practical, but by no means trivial (you will need a diff solution capable to resolve the conflicts between edited and new data).

Comment: Thnx you state exactly my problem. I can't see a solution as well. If I would forbid it to upload a new file the user has to make changes in the already existing content and then error's are easily made. Anyway Thank you for the feedback

Comment: I put your answer on "solved" because I still haven't found a solution and i don't think this is possible at all. So thank you for the effort